# Approximate c-chromatic number, each color class is P4-free (cograph)

Tags: cc.complexity-theory, graph-theory, graph-algorithms, approximation-algorithms, approximation-hardness

The classic chromatic number of graph, $\chi(G)$, describes the minimum number of colors needed so that each color class is an independent set. There are many other graph coloring definitions. One of them is **c-chromatic number**, $c(G)$, defined in the paper [Partitions of graphs into cographs](https://www.dropbox.com/s/tqxdkzgvnlte4v3/Partitions%20of%20graphs%20into%20cographs.pdf). It asks that each color class is a [cograph](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cograph). Cograph is a **P4-free** graph, i.e., there is no induced path of length 3.

"[G-free-complexity](https://www.dropbox.com/s/bz5936jzf9y32lq/G-free-complexity.pdf)" implies that it is NP-Complete decide $c(G)=k$ for any $k\ge 2$. I have thought following questions about (in-)approximating $c(G)$ for a while. Any suggestion is appreciated. Intuitively, I think these graph coloring are really hard to approximate.

This post is related to a previous one about [greedy coloring using a list](https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/21148/how-bad-can-the-greedy-coloring-list-color-for-the-c-chromatic-number-of-graph).

**Question 1**. Given a graph $G$ of $c(G)=2$, is it hard (e.g., unless P=NP. or any other hardness assumption) to partition $G$ into three cographs? How hard is it to approximate $c(G)$ for general graphs.

Related results of the classic $\chi(G)$. It is hard to 4-color a 3-colorable graph. There are many inapproximateness results from the well-known [`PCP theorem`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PCP_theorem). I tried to learn this theorem myself but it is hard for me to apply it to get inapproximate result of $c(G)$. I also tried `gap amplification` technique used to show it is hard to 2-approximate $\chi(G)$ by [Garey & Johnsn](https://www.dropbox.com/s/jmuebbzvhdo2ein/The%20complexity%20of%20near-optimal%20graph%20coloring.pdf).

**Question 2**. How good can we approximate $c(G)$ in polynomial time?

Related results. "[Approximate Hypergraph Coloring](https://www.dropbox.com/s/qfeoujxl140a90a/Approximate%20Hypergraph%20Coloring.pdf)" shows that, for any 4-uniform 2-colorable hypergraph $H$, there is a randomized algorithm to color $H$ using $O(n^{2/9}\log n)$ colors.
For any graph, [Remark 12](https://www.dropbox.com/s/tqxdkzgvnlte4v3/Partitions%20of%20graphs%20into%20cographs.pdf) shows that we can partition $G$ into at most $\lceil \frac{\Delta + 1}{2} \rceil $ cographs.

Any suggestion is welcome. A good tutorial or note of PCP Theorem (including application) is great. Thank you very much.